# Entity Framework doesn't update entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm writing app with C# WPF and I'm using a local `.mdf` database file, with Entity Framework to add/update data.

Unfortunately, my code doesn't work - there is no exception thrown, but updating/adding rows in tables doesn't apply any changes to the actual database file.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ESP] 
(
    [IdEsp]                INT          NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName]          NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [CryptoKey]            CHAR(64)     NOT NULL,
    [IP]                   VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    [MeasurementFrequency] INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdEsp] ASC)
);
```

Model class:

```
namespace RSZMT
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ESP
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ESP()
        {
            this.TempMeasurement = new HashSet<TempMeasurement>();
        }

        public ESP(int idEsp, string displayName, string cryptoKey, string iP, int measurementFrequency)
        {
            this.TempMeasurement = new HashSet<TempMeasurement>();
            this.IdEsp = idEsp;
            this.DisplayName = displayName;
            this.CryptoKey = cryptoKey;
            this.IP = iP;
            this.MeasurementFrequency = measurementFrequency;
        }

        public int IdEsp { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string CryptoKey { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public int MeasurementFrequency { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TempMeasurement> TempMeasurement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    RSZMT_DatabaseEntities dataEntities;

    private DataAccess()
    {
        dataEntities = new RSZMT_DatabaseEntities();
    }

    ~DataAccess()
    {
        dataEntities.Dispose();
    }

    private static DataAccess instance = new DataAccess();

    public static DataAccess GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    ...    

    public void ChangeEspName(int espId, string newName)
    {
        var ent = dataEntities.ESP.Where(s => s.IdEsp == espId).Single();
        ent.DisplayName = newName;
        dataEntities.ESP.AddOrUpdate(ent);
        var number = dataEntities.SaveChanges();               
    }
}
```

I have debugged this, and `dataEntites.SaveChanges()` returns 0 instead of 1 - rows affected.

Do you have any ideas, what is wrong with my code? Why it doesn't work?

Regards

**EDIT**: in the logs there is something like this:

```
2020-01-12 13:40:59.21 spid52      Setting database option OFFLINE to ON for database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF'.
2020-01-12 13:41:01.54 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2020-01-12 13:41:01.54 Logon       Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-P04PRDM\filip'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF'. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
2020-01-12 13:41:04.50 spid52      Starting up database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\BIN\DEBUG\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF'.
2020-01-12 13:41:04.52 spid52      Parallel redo is started for database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\BIN\DEBUG\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF' with worker pool size [4].
2020-01-12 13:41:04.52 spid52      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\BIN\DEBUG\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF' with worker pool size [4].
2020-01-12 13:41:11.55 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2020-01-12 13:41:11.55 Logon       Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-P04PRDM\filip'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF'. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
2020-01-12 13:41:24.23 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2020-01-12 13:41:24.23 Logon       Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-P04PRDM\filip'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'C:\USERS\FILIP\SOURCE\REPOS\RSZMT\RSZMT\RSZMT_DATABASE.MDF'. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
```

Comment: Why do you use `AddOrUpdate`? You can remove that line, although EF should save the change with or without it. Do you see EF run a SQL update statement?

Comment: I have tried .Attach() method, but didn't work as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if it run SQL update statement

Comment: AddOrUpdate is an extension, intended for migration only. An Update or Attach is not necessary, you modify 'ent' and call SaveChanges() to raise an update.
The SQL-Command you could see in visual studio in the diagnostic window, or  I use SQL Profiler, for SQL server. That displays every incoming command.

Comment: __Login failed__

Comment: Generated SQL Statement seems fine:

UPDATE [dbo].[ESP]
SET [DisplayName] = @0
WHERE ([IdEsp] = @1)

Comment: I don't know why in logs there is login failed, EF actually loads data to models without any problems, there is problem updating them

Comment: Now my update code is:

public void ChangeEspName(int espId, string newName)
        {
            var ent = dataEntities.ESP.Where(s => s.IdEsp == espId).Single();
            ent.DisplayName = newName;
            var number = dataEntities.SaveChanges();               
        }

Comment: Is the database attached to the Server?  Use SQL Server Management Studio and use explorer to see if the database is attached to the server.  It should be in the list of Databases.  What is the connection string?  What I think is happening is you are attaching the database (MDF file) in the connection string and the database is already attached to the server. So the server owns the file and is not allowing you to connected to the mdf file.  The connection string should not have an attach statement.  Instead you should just be referencing the database name in the server.

Comment: Connection string in App.config (auto-generated):
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RSZMT_DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RSZMT_Database_Model.csdl|res://*/RSZMT_Database_Model.ssdl|res://*/RSZMT_Database_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\RSZMT_Database.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: DB is local created in VS, I'm not using server, but I will install it in minutes

Comment: I've found 'solution' but there is something I can't explain.
When I start application from visual studio, database resets back every time when app is closed.
But when I start directly from source/bin/debug changes are saving.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: Finally I've made it. There is a property in Database.mdf file called "copy to the output directory" and by default it is set to "Always copy", and I changed it to "Never copy" and now everything works well. Thank you so much guys for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've made it. There is a property in Database.mdf file called "copy to the output directory" and by default it is set to "Always copy", and I changed it to "Never copy" and now everything works well. Thank you so much guys for all answers